# How to fill empty pixel from DEM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem

Is it possible to fill empty pixel from DEM (hgt file)?) in QGIS ? When I load it, and zoom to a big scale, some pixel without any value appear.  ( I have found a way using another software 3DEM on this link in french 
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Atelier_graphique/Didacticiels_cartographiques/Didacticiel_de_cr%C3%A9ation_de_carte_du_relief_bitmap
But is it possible with Qgis 2.6 Brighton to fill them ?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But first: Are you referring to SRTM files (hgt format)? And how large are the no-data areas, just pixels or more? Please edit your question.

Comment: Note that void filled SRTM data are available here: http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/ --> "Void-Filled "SRTM Plus" Released (SRTM NASA V3)"